# Nativescript Reuse xml template in code WITHOUT Angular

Tags: xml, typescript, nativescript

I just finished a nativescript application, but I’ve been asked to implement the Telerik-UI “RadSideDrawer”.
from the docs, I noticed huge chunks of xml I have to use on each page. I am using Typescript without Angular.
Is there a way to create a single xml template with just Typescript and reuse on all pages?. I know this can be done in  Angular, but I can’t start afresh just because of the sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, use custom components. You basically create a template and then reuse it on the pages when you need it. Just registering it on the page using its xmlns.

Once you declare the XML template somewhere that is your component. See the following posts for more detailed info.

https://www.google.com/amp/blog.bradleygore.com/2016/03/12/custom-nativescript-components/amp/

https://moduscreate.com/custom-components-in-nativescript/

Comment: Thanks alot Brad. I tried this with normal NativeScript components and it worked fine. It however gave "undefined" errors when I tried with the RadSideDrawer.  Could you give more pointers on how I could achieve this.   NB: I'm using the SideDrawerPage instead of the normal Page element in all my views